# What is a more crossplatform way of opening Explorer/file manager shell with the current directory?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a crossplatform way to open an OS's explorer or file manager gui.

This code is succinct and works on the Windows XP platform.  It allows the OS to select the user selected file-manager.  In my testing case it uses the default Explorer.exe.  This code opens the current working directory.

```
import os
os.startfile('.')
```

The Python documents says this works on the Windows platform.  It does not say it works on Unix or Mac platforms.

This also opens the Windows Explorer application in its own process leaving my Python app to continue running.  It appears to be a complete independant process as opposed to a subprocess because I can close or leave open either the caller Python program or the Windows Explorer without dependance on the other. (ie. one won't shut down the other on exit.)

What Python code, if any would open the default (or user selected) GUI file manager (to the current path) for other platforms, in a seperator process?

Comment: Windows and maybe OSX are the only systems where anyone would want such a behaviour. On Linux people tend to use the shell or some file manager they like - i.e. there is no specific one used by the vast majority of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX an easy way to do this is to use [`open`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/open', '~'])
```

Comment: Works for Windows too. Thanks.

Comment: @DevPlayer Do you want to say that `subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/open', '~'])` works for Windows? I doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux desktop system, you can expect the 'xdg-open' command to open a directory (or any file) with the default application for opening that file type. So just invoke that command from Python, for instance:

> import subprocess
>
> subprocess.call(['xdg-open', '.'])

Comment: Is this for all Linux distros or just a certain one?